# Angular 2 access directive from child template element

Tags: templates, angular, parent-child

I have a problem with angular 2 for two days and I came to get some help from you guys.

The problem is when I try to access a directive child declared within a  with ContentChild or ContentChildren from a parent component the Angular doesn't find any child. If I don't use template tag my parent component find the children without a problem.

[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sQNUUvLhtaTX8cX98ukQ?p=preview)

The parent ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit show that children QueryList has no results

My code is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ParentComponent} from './components/parent.component';
import {ChildDirective} from  './components/child.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

    <parent>
      <template>
        <button child>button 1 with child directive</button>
        <button child>button 2 with child directive</button>
      </template>

    </parent>


    `,

    directives: [ParentComponent, ChildDirective]

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

The Parent Component:

```
import {Component, ContentChild, ContentChildren, QueryList, 
TemplateRef, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ChildDirective} from './child.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    Parent Template

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></template>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit{

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  template:TemplateRef;

  @ContentChildren(ChildDirective)
  children:QueryList<ChildDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(this.children);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.children);
  }

}
```

The Child Directive

```
import {Directive, OnInit, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output} from    '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[child]',
})
export class ChildDirective implements OnInit{


  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('child started');
  }

  @Output()
  onClick:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter;

  @HostListener('click')
  onMouseEnter() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.onClick.emit('the child has been clicked.');
  }

}
```

Well, that's it, I wait some help cause I don't know what to do to solve this.

Thanks